# how to implement Netty ReferenceCounted in a custom class?

Tags: netty, bytebuffer, reference-counting

I have a Netty pipeline which handles FullHttpRequest. I want to create a codec that Converts this FullHttpRequest to a Custom POJO class. I don't want to copy the ByteBuf "fullHttpRequest.content()". The Pojo class will have a reference to the ByteBuf, but How do I implement the ReferenceCounting in the new Class since it contains the ByteBuf, it need to be reference counted isnt it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend `DefaultByteBufHolder` and pass the `ByteBuf` into the constructor. This will take care of all of this